# Erro de "else" sem "if" anterior

Tags: c

Estou tentando corrigir e errando sempre no mesmo lugar, sempre com o `if` e o `else` ou entre eles. O problema sempre ocorre com outros códigos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
    float a, b, c, deslta, x1, x2, raiz;
    printf ("Apesente os valores: ");
    scanf ("%f", &a);
    scanf ("%f", &b);
    scanf ("%f", &c);
    if (a = 0);
    printf ("Nao e uma equação do 2 grau\n");
    else
    delta=b^2 – 4*a*c
    if delta < 0
    printf ("Equacao nao possui raizes reais\n");
    else
    raiz=sqrt(delta);
    x1=(-b+raiz)/(2*a);
    x2=(-b-raiz)/(2*a);
    printf ("“O valor de X1 e X2 são: ", x1, x2);
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h> /* para sqrt */
int main() {
    float a, b, c, delta, x1, x2, raiz;
    printf ("Informe os valores de a, b e c: ");
    scanf ("%f", &a);
    scanf ("%f", &b);
    scanf ("%f", &c);
    if (a == 0)
        printf ("Nao e uma equação do 2 grau\n");
    else
        delta = b*b - 4*a*c; /* No lugar de b*b poderia utilizar pow(b, 2) */
    if (delta < 0)
        printf ("Equacao nao possui raizes reais\n");
    else {
        raiz = sqrt(delta);
        x1 = (-b+raiz)/(2*a);
        x2 = (-b-raiz)/(2*a);
        printf ("Raizes X1: %f e X2: %f\n", x1, x2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: o seguinte código esta apresentando o[Error] stray '\226' in program oque poderia ser ?

Comment: Em delta = b*b - 4*a*c; corrija o operador -. (- é diferente de –)

Answer (score 0):

Favor observar os parentesis e as chaves. No if você não pode colocar ; pois ele encerra o bloco.

```
int main () { 
   float a, b, c, deslta, x1, x2, raiz; 
   printf ("Apesente os valores: "); 
   scanf ("%f", &a); 
   scanf ("%f", &b); 
   scanf ("%f", &c); 
   **if (a == 0){**
    printf ("Nao e uma equação do 2 grau\n"); 
   }else{ 
     delta=(b^2) – (4*a*c);
     if (delta < 0) {
       printf ("Equacao nao possui raizes reais\n"); 
     }else{ 
       raiz=sqrt(delta); 
       x1=(-b+raiz)/(2*a); 
       x2=(-b-raiz)/(2*a); 
       printf ("“O valor de X1 e X2 são: ", x1, x2);
      } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

; Delimita o final de linha, não se coloca em if e else, pois ambos tem continuação.

= atribui valor a uma variavel, na 10 deve ser usado o operador == para denotar igualdade.

Outro erro que identifiquei foi que delta não está declarado (você escreveu errado na linha 5).

Eis um exemplo de código estruturado em blocos:

```
if(a == 0){

}else{
  delta = b^2-4*a*c;
  if(delta < 0){

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vários erros em sequencia no seu código. Vamos a um por um:

1. `if (a = 0)`

   Aqui você está atribuindo zero ao `a`, depois checando se esse valor é verdade (zero é falso). Logo você sobrescreve o valor original do `a` e a condicional sempre se resultará falsa. Para comparar igualdade use o `==`:

   ```
   if (a == 0)
   ```
2. `if (a == 0);`

   A condicional espera receber um comendo depois dela. Você teve a intenção de executar `printf ("Nao e uma equação do 2 grau\n");`, mas colocou um `;` ali. Isso por si só é um comando vazio. *Se `a` for zero, faça nada.* Aqui você provocou o problema com o `else`, afinal, como não há chaves `{ ... }` na condicional ela só pode receber um comando, e você pos dois em seguida. O segundo (o `printf`) está fora da condicional. Quando chega no `else` você já saiu da condicional e ele não sabe o que fazer.
3. `delta = b^2 - 4*a*c`

   Antes de mais nada, faltou um ponto e virgula no final. E mais importante: `^` **não é potência**. Esse operador faz **bitwise xor**. Para potência você pode usar `pow(b, 2)`. A função vem de `#include <math.h>`. Ou muito melhor: `b*b`.
4. `if delta < 0`

   Faltou parenteses! Deve ser `if (delta < 0)`.
5. `raiz = sqrt(delta);`

   De onde vem a função `sqrt`? Deveria incluir o `#include <math.h>` para isso funcionar.
6. `printf ("O valor de X1 e X2 são: ", x1, x2);`

   O `printf` não vai contatenar os valores para você. Ele também não sabe detectar os tipos de valores que você quer lidar. Use assim:

   ```
   printf ("O valor de X1 e X2 são: %g e %g", x1, x2);
   ```
7. Retorno

   Você declarou uma função `int main()`. Ela retorna um `int`, mas você não retornou um `int`! Sua função está retornando valor não especificado, que pode ser problemático. Adicione no final: `return 0;`. Traidicionalmente zero indica que não ocorreu nenhum erro. Pode usar um para erro. Ou outro valor qualquer de sua escolha.
8. Argumentos

   A função `int main()` pega qualquer quantidade de argumentos de qualquer tipo. Isso é ilegal para a função `main`. Ela deve ser: ou pega zero argumentos, ou pega um `int` e um `char**`. Defina ela assim para zero argumentos:

   ```
   int main(void)
   ```
9. `stray '\226' in program`

   Só é permitido usar caracteres ASCII em código C. Você usou coisas como `ç` ou `ã`. Também é provável que tenha digitado algum caractere invisível (não printável) no meio do código, confundindo o compilador.

Como pode ver, tinha muita coisa errada em um bloco tão pequeno. A maioria disso é pura falta de atenção com a sintaxe do C. Sugiro um estudo mais detalhado de como ela funciona.

Answer (score -2):

Dois erros comuns em novos programadores consistem em: Falta de atenção e não dar valor as boas práticas.

Note que você declarou a variável como "delsta" e a utiliza como "delta".

no if(a = 0) Você cometeu 2 erros. Um de usar um ";" onde não deveria e outro erro
que consiste em: quando você quiser testar/comparar 2 valores você usa "==" ou "!=". No seu caso , foi utilizado uma atribuição "=" .

E outra coisa, embora os professores de faculdade insistam em dizer que se usar apenas uma linha (e não um bloco) no if/else não precise de "{}", é de boas práticas usa-las sempre.